# .htaccess Rewrite URL as subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I have this url:

http://mysite.com/home.php?name=username

I want to be able to access that by going to:

http://mysite.com/home/username

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite. There are about three million questions exactly like this one, here's first result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260041/apache-htaccess-mod-rewrite-and-clean-urls

Comment: possible duplicate of [url rewrite .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473116/url-rewrite-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the mod_rewrite extention that comes with Apache.

Create a new `.htaccess` file in your web root directory, and populate it with the following text.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]*)$ home.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @user1123513 what error message are you getting when you try and access the rewritten URL?

Comment: Error 404.  The page is accessible from home.php?name=username

Comment: @user1123513 If home.php wasn't in your web root, then it wouldn't work - I've changed the code above so that it can be placed in any directory.